# how to delete a empty second row for css grid

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RKJS.png)

Hi guys, I'm trying to delete a row. I have attached a picture what I have right now. I only want 1 row and 3 column

```css
display: grid;
grid - template - rows: auto;
grid - template - columns: 1 fr 1 fr 1 fr;
```

```html
<div class="list-loan-info" ng-scrollbar rebuild-on="rebuild:me">
  <div automationid="FieldName" class="field-name" style="float:left;"> fieldName </div>
  <div automationid="OldValue" class="old-value">oldValue &nbsp;</div>
  <div automationid="NewValue" class="new-value-true">newValue</div>
  <div automationid="NewValue" class="new-value-false">newValue</div>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: please share also your html and js

Comment: @Alex I added html file. I just noticed that I have 4 divs which make sense but for the new-value-true and new-value-false should toggle, so when true is on i don't want to show false

Comment: you have also to do a position for your elements I will write an answer

Answer (score 0):

add a grid template rows to your code

```
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
```

Comment: @coolps881 so I need to add two different grid-template-rows?

Comment: no. one grid-template-columns and one grid-template-rows. of course if you have 4 divs this is not really possible unless you are conditionally rendering the last column

Comment: I'm conditionally rendering 4th div

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

- You have to set inside your wrapper div the grid and the layout with the amount of columns and rows and their sizes.

---

```
/* Here you define the grid */
    .list-loan-info {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1 fr 1 fr 1 fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1 fr;
    }
```

- Then you have to set the position of the child divs inside this wrapper div.
  You can set the position with
- grid-row
- grid-column

---

Here an example with all next to each other.

```css
.list-loan-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1 fr 1 fr 1 fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.field-Name {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  ;
}

.new-value-true {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  ;
}

.new-value-false {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 3;
  ;
}

.old-value {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-loan-info" ng-scrollbar rebuild-on="rebuild:me">
  <div automationid="FieldName" class="field-name" style="float:left;"> fieldName </div>
  <div automationid="OldValue" class="old-value">oldValue &nbsp;</div>
  <div automationid="NewValue" class="new-value-true">newValue</div>
  <div automationid="NewValue" class="new-value-false">newValue</div>
  <br />
</div>
```

As requested in the commentarys here an example where the columns are among each other.

```css
.list-loan-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1 fr 1 fr 1 fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.field-Name {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  ;
}

.new-value-true {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  ;
}

.new-value-false {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 3;
  ;
}

.old-value{
 grid-row: 1;
 grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-loan-info" ng-scrollbar rebuild-on="rebuild:me">
  <div automationid="FieldName" class="field-name" style="float:left;"> fieldName </div>
  <div automationid="OldValue" class="old-value">oldValue &nbsp;</div>
  <div automationid="NewValue" class="new-value-true">newValue</div>
  <div automationid="NewValue" class="new-value-false">newValue</div>
  <br />
</div>
```

Nice Reading for CSS Grid

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: if I want to set new-value-true and new-value-false to be on same column. I just need to set grid-column to same grid?

Comment: then you need a second row, you can define it in your layout above

Comment: then it will create empty space for second row :(

Comment: what do you mean? Wait I will update my answer. CSS Grid make such things really easy

Comment: you're welcome, if you think this was helpful mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below and I promise there won't be more than 3 rows. Let me know if you get any issues.

HTML-

```
<div class="list-loan-info" ng-scrollbar rebuild-on="rebuild:me">
  <div automationid="FieldName" class="field-name" style="float:left;"> fieldName </div>
  <div automationid="OldValue" class="old-value">oldValue &nbsp;</div>
  <div class='new-value'>
     <div automationid="NewValue" class="new-value-true">newValue</div>
     <div automationid="NewValue" class="new-value-false">newValue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.list-loan-info{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    column-gap: 2rem;
}

.new-value{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    column-gap: 1rem;
}
```